# Why Socket.io doesnt emit in a real live server?

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

I have a simple chat application, with react-native, nodejs, socket.io and express.

this app is working fine on my laptop as I am using local nodejs server with epxress

Now I am using real live server from hostwinds Here I have setuped nodejs+express server. Here the connection works well, but problem is it doesnt emit from client or from server, I mean First time it connects to server successfully, but doesnt emit event or send data.

My client code is:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

class InitSocket extends Component{
  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.socket = io('http://LiveServerIP:3000/', { transports: ['websocket'] });
        this.socket.emit('onsenddata', 'Hello from client to server');
  }
}
```

The above code emit('onsenddata', 'some data'); just works some times, but most of the time does not works. Here in above code as you can see I am using the hostwinds live server ip address.

following code works very well, while is the same as above code, just it is in my laptop and ip address is localhost:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

class InitSocket extends Component{
  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000/', { transports: ['websocket'] });
        this.socket.emit('onsenddata', 'Hello from client to server');
  }
}
```

My server code is:

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = 3000;
io.on('connection', cs => {

  cs.on('onsenddata', username => {
       cs.broadcast.to(cs.id).emit('onsenddata', 'Hello from server to client');
  });

});

server.listen(port, err => {
    if(err){
        console.error("Some Error: "+err);
    }else{
        console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was componentDidMount fires before socket is ready, now solved, using settimeout function.

```
componentDidMount(){
   setTimeout(()=>{
     this.socket.on('onreceiveddata', message =>{
        console.log(message);
     });
   }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me on heroku:

client:

```
const socket = socketIO('https://myserver.onheroku.com', {
  transports: ['websocket'], 
  jsonp: false 
}); 
socket.connect(); 
socket.on('connect', () => { 
  console.log('connected to socket server'); 
});
socket.emit('onsenddata', 'Hello from client to server');
```

server:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketIO(server);
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('client connected on websocket');
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('server started and listening on port ' + PORT);
});

server.listen(port, err => {
    if(err){
        console.error("Some Error: "+err);
    }else{
        console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please help me why on **hostwinds** does not work
there the diffrence is just with **https** and **jsonp**

Comment: Try to use my code example if it works so change your code

Comment: Host does not have free ssl so I can not use https, I only use http

Answer (score 1):

Heroku will not use Port 3000, try using *process.env.PORT* which is set by Heroku before deploying app.

Server Code:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

Client Code (HEROKU_APP_URL is URL of your deployed Heroku App):

```
this.socket = io(HEROKU_APP_URL, { transports: ['websocket'] });
```

Comment: THank you, I am using hostwinds